# Is there a way to trace the origin of a print job on a wireless printer?

Tags: wireless-networking, printing, printer, network-printer

So I had a weird thing happen today—a print job showed up in the tray of my wireless HP printer (HP OfficeJet Pro 6960 in case anyone cares) that nobody in my house had printed. The most annoying thing is that this print job appeared to be several copies of a blown-up image taken of a phone screen, so the screen's contents in the middle were white but there's a *ton* of black around the edges and it wasted half our ink cartridge. Is there any way to look into some sort of print history log and see where that print job came from? I've tried to do a little research on this topic but so far have only figured out how to enable logging of future print jobs or else look and see what's currently queued up to print, neither of which solve this problem.

A little more background: this printer is currently connected to my home wifi network. I logged into my router's admin page and didn't recognize any unfamiliar devices connected to our network—it was all just our usual cellphones and laptops. I was discussing this with my sister though and she was under the impression that the printer was discoverable by nearby devices even if they're not connected to our network, but I'm not sure. There's also a unique email address that can be used to print things remotely. I use this quite a bit, such as when I receive my pay stub at work—you just attach the image or document you want to print and email it to the printer from wherever you are, so if someone somehow had that email address, I suppose that could've been the origin of this strange print job.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

[I would try a firmware update](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/swdetails/hp-officejet-pro-6960-all-in-one-printer-series/8289579/swItemId/bi-215266-4)

> Note
>
> Reminder: Dynamic security enabled printer. This Firmware includes dynamic security measures, which may prevent supplies with non-HP chips or circuitry from working now or in the future. More at: [www.hp.com/go/learnaboutsupplies](http://www.hp.com/go/learnaboutsupplies).
>
> Note: For printers manufactured prior to December 1, 2016 dynamic security will not be enabled by this firmware.

[Your support page](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-officejet-pro-6960-all-in-one-printer-series/8289579)